# Density of Rational Numbers in Lowest Terms in R

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have a question about the density of the rational numbers when they're strictly in lowest terms in $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm looking at all rational numbers in lowest terms, $\frac{p}{q} \in [0,1]$, and I've only considered those with denominators up to $n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Pick an arbitrary irrational number and find the two rationals closest to it (one on the left and one on the right) out of the ones that I said I've considered so far.

I want it to be sandwiched between two rationals whose denominators are at least $n$. If they are already then that's great and I'm done. But if at least one of two rationals on either side has a denominator smaller than $n$ I want to keep adding rationals in lowest terms until it's between two of them with denominator at least $n$.

I'm curious if it's even possible to do this. I'm hoping there's some kind of density argument that can be used. For example, say that the left rational has a denominator lower than $n$. Then since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there has to be another rational number between the irrational and its left boundary and since I used up all rationals with denominators less than or equal to $n$ this one has to be greater than $n$.

Can I do this if all the rationals I'm considering are in lowest terms?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say a rational number is "in lowest terms." This is not a property of the number, it is a property of a particular representation as a quotient of two integers.

Comment: If I alter my language to say that I'm considering  all real numbers in [0,1] that can be represented as a quotient of integers in lowest terms, then is there a way to show that I can eventually sandwich any arbitrary irrational number between 2 whose representation has a denominator of at least n?

Comment: @Confused yes, see the answers below. By the way, any rational number can be expressed as a fraction in lowest terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you’ve clearly stated what you want to do, but I’ll speculate and try to answer.

You seem interested in the following: Given one irrational number $x$, consider *all* the rational numbers that can be written using denominators of $n$ or smaller.

One of these rational numbers, $a$, is closest to $x$ on the left, and another one, $b$, is closest to $x$ on the right, so $a< x < b$. Write $a$ and $b$ in lowest terms and see if the denominators are both exactly $n$.

Sometimes they are, and sometimes they aren’t. If they aren’t, I think you want to know if you can always consider somewhat larger denominators and then have it be the case that within this *new* set of more rationals, the ones closest to $x$ (left and right) both have denominator at least $n$.

The answer is yes.

Suppose for some $n$, you find $a$ and $b$ closest on each side of $x$, but unfortunately one or both of $a$ and $b$ can be written with denominators smaller than $n$ when you reduce to lowest terms.

Ok, so pick *any* pair of rational numbers closer in to $x$, again one on each side: $a <a'<x < b'< b$. (There are always ones to pick.)

You didn’t pick $a'$ or $b'$ before, so that means they weren’t in the first set of rationals you looked at. So *they* can’t be written with a denominator of $n$ or smaller, even in lowest terms, or you would have picked one of them instead of $a$ or $b$ the first time around.

That means you can increase the denominators you consider up to the larger of the denominators of $a'$ and $b'$. (You can’t really say “the denominators,” since there are infinitely many ways to pick a denominator for a given rational number, but write them any way you want — lowest terms isn’t needed.) Suppose the bigger denominator is $M$, and now include all the rationals with denominators up to $M$.

Now $a'$ and $b'$ might not be the closest ones to $x$ among this new set of rationals, so, *again* choose the closest left and right, so you’ll have $a < a'\le a''< x < b''\le b'< b$. The rational numbers $a''$ and $b''$ have to be the pair you were looking for. They are the closest (left and right) among all rationals with denominators up to a given point ($M$), but they must have denominators greater than $n$ in lowest terms, because you didn’t find them the first time around.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was aiming for. I apologize for the wording of my original question and really appreciate you writing out a detailed response like this.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a prime $p\ge n$ such that $\frac1p<\min\{\alpha-\lfloor\alpha\rfloor,\lceil\alpha\rceil-\alpha\}$. If your irrational number is $\alpha$, there is a unique integer $n$ such that

$$\frac{n}p<\alpha<\frac{n+1}p\;,$$

and these fractions are in lowest terms, since neither $\frac{n}p$ nor $\frac{n+1}p$ is an integer.

Comment: Thanks. I need a bit of time to absorb this but I was wondering if I could ask a follow-up. Using your method is it guaranteed that there are no numbers whose representations have a denominator less than n come between the irrational and n/p or the irrational and (n+1)/p? I need the closest number on the left and the closest number on the right to have denominator greater than or equal to n. Yes or no answer is sufficient, I just want to make sure we're on the same page when I try to digest this.

Comment: @Confused: No, there’s no guarantee. Suppose that $\frac19<\alpha<\frac18$ and $n=8$. Then my suggestion will get you $\alpha$ between consecutive elevenths instead of between $\frac19$ and $\frac29$.

Answer (score 2):

if you take all the numbers of the form 
$$
\frac{k}{p}
$$
with $p$ prime these form $p$ subintervals of the same length of $[0,1]$ and your irrational must lie in one of them. Taking $p$ as big as you want, you can make the intervals as small as you want. Since $p$ is prime, the fractions are in lowest terms.

Comment: @Matt: It’s still a problem: you don’t want your irrational to be in $[0,1/p]$ or $[1-1/p,1]$.